# Поиск плагина для скролла

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

всем привет, на сайте поставил плагин https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr
но он на телефоне работает просто ужасно

подскажите аналогичный плагин, задача привязать блок к "скроллированию", сделать так чтобы анимация проходила постепенно при скролле

Comment: возможно эти: https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript#scroll

Answer (score 0):

jquery.scroolly умеет все что надо. и под мобильными.